# SQL Server two-way cascade?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to put together a database in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 which will manage the data without having to programatically process the data but I'm having some issues at the moment.

I have a main table called person, this table holds core data about a person and this is linked to a second table called customer in which they are included if they wish to have transaction permissions. Once a transaction has taken place the customer ID is placed into the transaction table.

```
|Person|   |Customer|   |Transaction|
|------|   |--------|   |-----------|
|  ID  |-\ |   ID   |-\ |    ID     |
|      |  \| person |  \|  Customer |
|      |   |        |   |           |
```

Of the two links, the ID's are PK's and the secondary items (person/customer) are FK's.
The problem I am having with this arrangement lies in the requirement that a person has to be kept if they have made a transaction and thus their customer ID appears in the transaction table.

I am not 100% sure on what approach to take, would a 'Delete Rule - Cascade' between person-customer with a 'Delete Rule - No Action' between Customer - Transaction create the desired effect?

Any thoughts approach or a better approach would be very much appreciated on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, yes, an

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

clause in `Customer.Person` foreign key, and an

```
ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

clause in `Transaction.Customer` foreign key would have the desired effect.

Then any attemp to delete a Person, will delete the related Customer row, unless there are related Transcations. That will raise an error and the DELETE would be rolled back.

Comment: @Jvr, If this is best answers your question, make sure to mark it as accepted by clicking the little check mark to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You could just have a delete trigger on the person table that stops the delete if the to-be-deleted person has any records in the Transaction table.